# How to run bash command using cloudbuild

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Trying to run a bash command that creates a directory in GCP but getting an error

> "create_directory": Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/cloud-builders/bash:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/cloud-builders/bash/manifests/latest".

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/bash:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - 'mkdir my_dir'
    id: "create_directory"
```

I'm able to create it in cloud shell by running
`mkdir my_dir`

How do i resolve this?

Comment: note that that the bash builder may not have all the tools you need like 'curl'. you may do better with the gcloud builder image

Answer (score 3):

usually I do something like this (pay attention to the builder name, and use commands without quote signs):

```
  - id: "some identifier"
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |

        echo "something"
```

Comment: You can also do things using the scripts field 
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts